# Javascript: getElementsByClassName not giving all elements

Tags: javascript, html

Well i put tablerows with a classname "gone" in my Html like this:

```
 <tr class="gone">
        <th>text</th>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gone">
        <th>text</th>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gone">
        <th>text</th>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gone">
        <th>text</th>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gone">
        <th>text</th>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gone">
        <th>text</th>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
```

and when i get my elements in javascript with this code:

```
var arrayelements=document.getElementsByClassName('gone');
var arrlength=arrayelements.length;
for(var i=0;i<arrlength;i++){
    arrayelements[i].setAttribute("class","there");
    console.log(arrayelements);
}
```

the return value of my console.log is

```
> <tr class="there">...</tr> 
> <tr class="there">...</tr>
> <tr class="there">...</tr>
> undefined
```

the next time i run it the result is

```
> <tr class="there">...</tr> 
> <tr class="there">...</tr>
> undefined
```

i don't understand why it is suddenly undefined

Comment: Man, `undefined` is okay, coz whatever you are doing doesn't return anything. So it is so. But, let me try to repro.

Comment: Shouldn't console.log be outside the loop? Or do you mean to log arrayelements[i] within the loop? Or your goal really is to see it all step by step?

Comment: yeah meant arrayelements[i]...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the HTMLCollection returned by `getElementsByClassName` is a LIVE LIST ... by changing the class, you change the list during the for loop!

One solution is to "copy" the list to an array

```
var arrayelements=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('gone'));
var arrlength=arrayelements.length;
for(var i=0;i<arrlength;i++){
    arrayelements[i].setAttribute("class","there");
    console.log(arrayelements);
}
```

Another method would be to start at the end of the list and work backwards

```
var arrayelements=document.getElementsByClassName('gone');
var arrlength=arrayelements.length;
for(var i=arrayelements.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    arrayelements[i].setAttribute("class","there");
    console.log(arrayelements);
}
```

or another - always work on the first element, seeing as you're always shrinking the length

```
var arrayelements=document.getElementsByClassName('gone');
while(arrayelements.length) {
    arrayelements[0].setAttribute("class","there");
}
```

I would recommend the first as the easiest to work with, and avoid the last method :p

Comment: Now I got it...

Comment: thanks it works, they didn't say that on school so i was really confused